# Signature used for android Native Application

Tags: robotium

I am trying to make test cases for android native apps using robotium. But for certain apps I get an error "the signature does not match the target package".
Is there any possible way to know the signature to be used for the android native apps?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use this: http://www.troido.de/re-sign.jar (run it as root or administrator) to resign your app, signing it using your debug keystore. 
In this document you'll find more informations about all the procedure!
Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

Not for native apps. This is one of the "problems" with `Robotium`, in that the signatures have to match. `Robotium` claims that they are able to do "black box" testing, but you have to have a matching signature, which isn't always available. One option is that you can try to remove the old signature, and create a new one using the debug signature.

Here is an excerpt from a `Robotium` document that might help:

```
    Signature:
The signature will identify the author of the android application. Signature means it contains the information like first name and last name of the developer, Name of the organizational unit, organization, city, state, two-­‐letter country code.
Standard tools like Keytool and Jarsigner are used to generate keys and sign applications. [For more help: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-­‐signing.html ]
IMPORTANT STEPS:
* If you know the certificate signature then you need to use the same signature in your test project
* If you do not know the certificate signature then you need to delete the certificate signature and you should use the same android debug key signature in both the application and the test project
* If the application is unsigned then you need to sign the application apk with the android debug key
If the application is signed then you can use the following drag and drop java program to resign it:
http://www.troido.de/re-­‐sign.jar
Or
-­‐-­‐ Un-­‐zip the apk file
-­‐-­‐ Delete the META-­‐INF folder
-­‐-­‐ Re-­‐zip the apk file
-­‐-­‐ In Dos prompt /Command prompt
> jarsigner -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android ApplicationToTest.apk androiddebugkey
> zipalign 4 ApplicationToTest.apk TempApplicationToTest.apk
Then rename TempApplicationToTest.apk to ApplicationToTest.apk
```

Best of luck!